# How do I COPY a CSV into pgadmin4 on Manjaro/Arch Linux? (Permissions problems)

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am running Manjaro Linux and trying to learn how to use PostgresSQL.  I have installed Postgres [according to the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL), and installed pgAdmin4 via pacman as well.  I have set up a server and a database using the pgAdmin4 GUI, and have begun to do basic SQL queries.

I am attempting to import a csv, which is on my disk at `/home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv`. In a Query Tool panel, I have created the birdsong table with

```
-- Drop table if exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bird_song;

-- Create new table
CREATE TABLE birdsong (
    english_name VARCHAR,
    country VARCHAR,
    latitude DEC,
    longitude DEC
 );

 COPY birdsong (english_name, country, latitude, longitude)
 FROM '/home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

and I am getting the error `ERROR:  could not open file "/home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv" for reading: Permission denied`

I am on PostgresSQL 12.1, and pgAdmin4 4.15. Incidentally, when I start pgAdmin4 it complains that the most current version is 4.17, but I have not yet figured out whether/how to upgrade that.

How do I arrange the correct permissions settings to read files into pgAdmin4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the database has no permission to access the file `/home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv`. You need to grant access to the database user - normally called `postgres`. Check how to do that in your operating system, e.g. [`chown`](https://www.howtogeek.com/438435/how-to-use-the-chown-command-on-linux/) in Linux and try to use COPY again.

```
 COPY birdsong (english_name, country, latitude, longitude)
 FROM '/home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

In case you don't have the necessary permissions to grant access to the user `postgres` in your system, you can use the `STDIN` facility of `COPY` via [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

```
$ cat birdsong.csv | psql your_db -c "COPY birdsong (english_name, country, latitude, longitude) DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER FROM STDIN;"
```

This approach can be also useful if you plan to use `COPY` to import files into remote databases.

### Slightly unrelated note

I notice you're importing `longitude` and `latitude` values into your table in separated columns, which for the sake of importing data is just fine. However, if you're planing to perform spatial operations with this data, I would recommend you to store these coordinates in a `geometry` or `geography` column. This is how you can do this:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','birdsong','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE birdsong ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point,4326);
```

.. and then fill up the `geom` column with a point

```
UPDATE birdsong SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326);
```

The number 4326 stands for the SRS `WGS84` - most used SRS.

Further reading:

- [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)
- [`AddGeometryColumn`](https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable read access to the file from the pgadmin service by running the following:

```
chmod o+rx /home/rob
chmod o+xr /home/rob/Code
chmod o+xr /home/rob/Code/temp
chmod o+r /home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv
```

Be careful though, this may not be exactly desirable. Another option would be to copy the file into a shared location and add read permission. Say

```
cp /home/rob/Code/temp/birdsong.csv /tmp
chmod o+r /tmp/birdsong.csv
```

... Then change your SQL to copy from the new location.